# how to get cognito redirects to work with angular V6

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use aws cognito with angular6.  Proving to be a disaster

I use google auth and I get the below in the browsers URL.  congnito successfully redirects to my page.  Great.  Now what?

```
http://localhost:4200/#id_token=eyJraWQiOiJhTXRTYko0VDJreStHRnBCQWg5K3JLZmt5QWvwt9yE_rNmja9mh6gMCDOy0g3JPC1WkwjEmU9YdEW5MQqHAurYUoidAHCB6GjEHBob-1O_bu_hLowhDCucWVeCzhfMNw&access_token=eyJraWQiOiJLMTZ1ZmVURWE1dmRPamU5aTJReXkycGVDWnVQeE1TR1p5VWZwV3NvaEM4PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiI3YTgxNmU0Yi0zMTVkLTRkMmMtOWFhYS04MzIzNWFjMWU1NWUiLCJjb2duaXRvOmdyb3VwcyI6WyJ1cy1lYXN0LTFfYmx6dFlsImp0aSI6IjAwNjJhODI1LTVmMmEtNDZkNi04N2FlLTkzYTc5MTlhMDVkMyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IjNlMGR1YWdwY3NoMmdhNmRkbm5lNXI4ajltIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJHb29nbGVfMTE2MDA1Nzg1NjQ1MjgzNTEyMjM2In0.dwlRhohhYYUmgIpH7H8kgOV6W4k_E3nv-ty0tnHD043dErrliUKxST-7Sj0zzHCfe6JrUJv417vlU3sD1BYs6bMYKFoygdWp7RMuAQXC8o6TqHEpviOHwElVgVEQ0JY9twui3q_2mOL7yoKlWdax8c46sGtaLILRdm0YSoI0gGqwCYCCgWT4LZ424wdRVxJtBfB-gXKmQr6Z24Co7-7-9aDaYRiVMrFRywTwY_mxuViEZYQ9JJ432_d-EgYp9zfsATNQ26Iaol50Sdq36UL_kfWrnXaJR-itkfwLLAtDj-kTQCUYM3vfzF65E7f0IFHNqc0MAWB5O8wZoWpr_FI9iQ&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer
```

1. What is the deal with `#id_token=eyJraWQ....`? I get get the query string it `returns {}`

   ```
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
                 console.log(params)
               })
   ```

   How do I access in Angular?
2. I tried the below:

   ```
       import {AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserAttribute, CognitoUserPool} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
       import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';


   const PoolData = {
     UserPoolId: "us-east-1_sgsdfgsfd",
     ClientId: "3e0d5r8j9m"  
   };
   const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(PoolData);   
   var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
   ```
3. If I use `RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })` I get the below error.  So I had to set to false

   ```
   core.js:1624 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'
   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'
   ```

Net Net...

cognitoUser return null

This leaves me nowhere to go.

How do I create cognitoUser? Or at least get the `jwt in token_id`?

Comment: You want the `fragment`, not the `queryParams`

Comment: Then how to I get from fragment?

Comment: The same way you get the query params, but using the correct property name.

Comment: @Tampa were you able to resolve this issue? if yes, please add the answer